# Is it recommended to edit the index.html file when working on a React.js project?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm just starting to work with React.js, and I've noticed how some people modify their index.html file and some don't.  Is it recommended to render out the whole project with JSX by calling ReactDOM, or should I structure the project with the basic HTML, CSS, JS combo and then just add React to certain parts that will be constantly modified?  For example: Should a static home screen be made with HTML, CSS, and JS, and then where aspects of the project will be more interactive React would be used?

Comment: There is no correct answer to your question, it is 100% opinion and use-case based.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Marty said, you can use either of the methodology as and when required.